# Eclipse - turn generic project into a Scala project

Tags: eclipse, git, scala

I am having problems in converting generic project into a Scala project in Eclipse.

I made a new repository into gitlab and git cloned it into a folder. I imported the file into Eclipse by doing Import -> Git -> Projects from git -> Existing local repository -> "my project" -> import as generic project -> next -> Finish.

Now I would like to make this project into a Scala project. I found some instruction for this where they said that I should make a new Scala project and copy all the necessary folders from there after unselecting Filters -> exclude * resources. I did this, but it seems that I cannot copy the Scala libraries from the new Scala project "test" nevertheless.

If someone has some ideas how to turn the project 3d-modelling-program into a Scala project I would highly appreciate it.

you can find a picture of the situation below. Thanks for the help!

[image: Image of the situation]

Comment: do you have scala plugin installed in eclipse ?

Comment: yes I have a Scala plugin installed

Answer (score 0):

you just need to generate the eclipse project files with the sbt plugin **sbteclipse**.
Just add this line to the file ../project/plugins.sbt (create the file if it does not exist)

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.4")
```

This works for my sbt version. If you want to understand how to set the plugin version please visit the official documentation: [enter link description here](https://github.com/sbt/sbteclipse)

After that you have to navigate to the project directory from the console and type

`sbt eclipse`

this will generate the required eclipse project files.
Then go back to eclipse and refresh the project.
You may need to adjust the scala version in the project properties under "scala compiler".

Hope this helps,

BR Paul